# How to capture ProcMon logs when coming out of OOBE?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, logging, procmon

I need to capture procmon logs to analyze a hang that occurs right after windows OOBE. I need boot tracing logs.

I have tried enabling boot logging through the UI - doesn't work because OOBE reboots multiple times and only the first reboot is captured by procmon.

I have also looked here: [how to enable procmon boot logging for every boot?](https://superuser.com/questions/502671/how-to-enable-procmon-boot-logging-for-every-boot). Most of the comments seem to tell the OP to simply not do what he is trying to do, which is very frustrating as I have a legitimate reason for needing to do so. I did try the first solution but it seems not to work. I think perhaps my custom script to enable those regkeys does not run during the OOBE reboots.

How can I capture procmon logs of the OOBE process and immediately afterward?

Comment: is safe mode stable? did you want to edit autoruns.exe if so?   safe mode option shows after a couple aborted boots under Advanced

Comment: @TonyStewart Can you elaborate? You're saying I can boot to safe mode and edit a file called autoruns.exe to make procmon start boot logging on every boot?

Comment: no but you can fix your boot problems perhaps with some work creating log files